# Makefile $wildcard only matches top directory

Tags: directory, make, recursive

I am trying to implement a makefile for my C project which has a directory structure as follows:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER:
    folder1
    folder2
    folder // n number of folders
    main.c

FOLDER1:
    subfolder1
    subfolder // n number of subfolders
```

And subfolder 1 can have further subfolders etc.. etc..

I don't intend on being stupid with my directory structure, the deepest I may go is 1-2 MAYBE 3.

Thus far I have:

```
# A Makefile to build our First_Game_2 project

dirs = * */parse

PROJECT =  main
HEADERS =  $(PROJECT).h
OBJ     =  $(foreach dirz, $(dirs), \
        \
        $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(dirz).c)) \
        \
    )

C99     =  gcc -std=c99
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -pedantic -Werror 

$(PROJECT) : $(OBJ)
        $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJ)


%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
        $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
        rm -f $(PROJECT) $(OBJ)
```

My problem is if `parse` contains a subfolder, say `test` to give the structure

```
PROJECT_FOLDER/parse/test
```

In such a case, nothing is returned from

```
$(foreach dirz, $(dirs), \
        \
        $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(dirz).c)) \
        \
    )
```

I tested the output of the function with the following makefile

```
# A Makefile to build our First_Game_2 project

dirs = * */parse

PROJECT =  main
HEADERS =  $(PROJECT).h
OBJ     =  

C99     =  gcc -std=c99
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -pedantic -Werror 

$(foreach dirz, $(dirs), \
        \
        $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(dirz).c)) \
        \
    )
```

Which, given a structure of:

```
dirs = * */parse */parse/test
```

Produces an output of:

```
main.o parse/parse.o
```

Ignoring `*/parse/test`

Why is this the case, what can I do to fix my OBJ assignment to recognize `*/parse/test` or otherwise?

Comment: What `make` is it? Incredible, but there are waaaaay more `make` variants out there than RMS wants to make us believe ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wildcard in the `dirs` pattern backward.
You wanted:

```
dirs = * parse/* parse/test/*
```

As written, your pattern above expanded to: `*.c` (good), `*/parse.c` (lucky!), and `*/parse/test.c`, which would have confused you even more if that file existed.
The only reason it looked like it worked for the first level directory is because you used the same filename, 'parse', as the directory name.

Comment: I think `VPATH`, assuming GNU make` might also make a difference here. But so far I always went with schemes such as `$(wildcard ...)` or `$(shell find -...)` to include the correct files. One just has to be careful if out-of-tree builds are intended. +1

Comment: @ckchan oh wow, that's was silly of me :S - It seems my clean function isn't being implemented now, as I was hoping to replace `$(OBJ)` with my ~$(foreach` logic, any ideas why `clean:` isn't running?

Comment: @tsujp: seems like that would be unrelated to `clean`; if it's really not running at all, make sure it isn't something obvious like a file/dir called "clean". If not, try `make -d` to get more detail on what make is considering.

Comment: It seems that having a file `main.h` results in object files being created in the root directory, no matter what directory they come from. E.g. `main.o` and `parse.o` are inside the same folder instead of `parse.o` being inside the `parse` folder. Conversely renaming `main.h` to say... `includes.h` results in ISO C90 warnings, even though I clearly state -std=c99. The makefile is UNCHAINED except for your answer. As for `clean` near this line from `make -d` : `Successfully remade target file `main'.` there is no mention of `clean`, neither does scrolling through the terminal. This is annoying.

Comment: Or you use: `dirs = * */* */*/*` then it is recursive, but only 3 levels deep...